# How to manually build a nanobind extension?

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to manually build the example extension for nanobind:

```
// main.cpp
#include <nanobind/nanobind.h>

int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

NB_MODULE(my_ext, m) {
    m.def("add", &add);
}
```

> g++ -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I./nanobind/include main.cpp libnanobind.a /usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8-pic.a -std=c++17 -shared -fPIC -O3 -o my_ext.so

```
# main.py
import my_ext
print (my_ext.add(1, 2))
```

But, I am getting this error:

```
Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_Get(): no current thread state
Current thread 0x00007f77aea1e740 (most recent call first):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043 in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583 in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
File "main.py", line 1 in <module>
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have looked around and it says it is due to a mismatch between python versions. I am building `libnanobind.a` with `-I /usr/include/python3.8` and as far as I can tell, the versions are the same, so I am not sure what else to check.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Oh dear, I was running `python3 main.py` instead of `python3.8 main.py`.